# Why does cleanUp runs on only unmount if dependencies array is empty in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies, react-state-management

The react documentation says, If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument.

But it is in controdiction with the behaviour if some values are passed to dependency array in useEffect.

e.g:

```
useEffect(()=> {
  console.log('effect ran')
  return cleanupAction(){console.log('cleanup action')}
}, [props.value])
```

Here for every render when the effect will run, a cleanup will run before next render.
so, cleanup will only run if the effect was run.

but in other scenario.

```
useEffect(()=> {
  console.log('effect ran')
  return cleanupAction(){console.log('cleanup action')}
}, [])
```

Here in this case, the effect will run only on first render. and I expect the cleanup to run only before the second render. Then, why does the cleanup runs on unmount.

Because, I assume, when a render caused a effect to run. a cleanup will run before next render. So, it is not happening in this case.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand your question. In your second case, are you saying that the empty dependency useEffect cleanup is not running after next render?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, I was wrong in my understanding so, cleanup is run before next effect not before render. and on unmount. That is why , this behaviour is expected.